# Can't post variables to Parse JS API

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parse-platform

I'm trying to make a sample page where I can fill in some forms and then save the data to Parse API. I tried this using strings first, like this:

```
var Billing = Parse.Object.extend("Billing");
var billing = new Billing();

billing.set("First Name", "John");
billing.set("Last Name", "Doe");
billing.set("Email", "admin@parse.com");
```

That did work fine, but when I just wrote a variable, I get an error "POST 400 Bad Request" :

```
var Billing = Parse.Object.extend("Billing");
var billing = new Billing();

billing.set("First Name", frnm);
billing.set("Last Name", lsnm);
billing.set("Email", eml);
```

Why is that? I can't seem to find another way to make it work...
See my full coded gist here [here](https://gist.github.com/jackbillstrom/f566950acfb07b4f07e0)

Comment: If you log/alert one of your variables right after `billing.set("First Name", frnm);` like `console.log(frnm)`, does it have a value?

Comment: Now I see that "frnm" is not defined, I've added a gist to my question containing full code

Answer (score 0):

I used:

```
document.getElementById("card_cvNumber").value;
```

Instead of:

```
$('#card_cvNumber').val();
```

And the Parse JS:

```
var Billing = Parse.Object.extend("Billing");
var billing = new Billing();
    billing.save({Firstname: frnm, Lastname: lsnm, Company: cpnm, Adress: str1, City: cty, State: stat, PostalCode: zpc, Country: ctry, Phone: phn, Fax: fx, Email: eml}, {
          success: function(object) {
            alert("Success");
         }
});
```

It worked just great!